# Use private method/var in finalization

Tags: delphi, properties, static, delphi-xe6, finalize

i have (static) Class GT_MyClass

```
GT_MyClass = class
private
  class var FImage : TJpegImage;

  class function GetImage: TJpegImage;
public
  property Image : TJpegImage  read GetImage;
end;
```

in function GetImage I´m creating FImage if it doesnt exists yet.

```
class function GT_Myclass.GetImage: TJpegImage;
begin
    if not Assigned(FImage) then
    begin
      FImage := TJpegImage.Create;
    end;
    Result := FImage;
end;
```

and in finalization i want to FreeAndNil(FImage)

```
finalization
  if Assigned(FImage) then
    FreeAndNil(FImage);
```

but in finalization block i cant see private var FImage...

Please can you help me?

Thanks!

BTW: I want to property Image be absolutely static

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a difference in scope. In the class method, `GT_MyClass.GetImage` your code is in the scope of the class and so can see the class members. The finalization section executes in global scope. So you could make your code compile by qualifying the name:

```
finalization
  if Assigned(GT_MyClass.FImage) then
    FreeAndNil(GT_MyClass.FImage);
```

In fact, testing for `GT_MyClass.FImage` being assigned is pointless since `Free` already does that. So you would write:

```
finalization
  FreeAndNil(GT_MyClass.FImage);
```

Or you could provide another method of the class which better encapsulates this:

```
type
  GT_MyClass = class
  private
    class var FImage : TJpegImage;
    class function GetImage: TJpegImage;
    class procedure Finalize;
  public
    property Image : TJpegImage  read GetImage;
  end;
....
class procedure GT_MyClass.Finalize;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FImage); // in scope of class, no need to qualify
end;
....
finalization
  GT_MyClass.Finalize;
```

But this still leaves you calling a private method from outside the class which is not ideal. So you could use a [class destructor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Class_Destructors), which is executed from the unit's finalization code:

```
type
  GT_MyClass = class
  private
    class var FImage : TJpegImage;
    class function GetImage: TJpegImage;
    class destructor ClassDestroy;
  public
    property Image : TJpegImage  read GetImage;
  end;
....
class destructor GT_MyClass.ClassDestroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FImage); // in scope of class, no need to qualify
end;
```

No finalization code is needed, the compiler automatically makes sure the class destructor is called.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Beautiful solution (class destructor).

Comment: Why, oh why on earth `FreeAndNil`? This is the end of life of the entire program. Nothing will (or can) ever access it anymore. This is so disappointing.

Comment: @rudy I followed the lead of the asker. Perhaps you meant to address the question to them? I also didn't want to start up the old religious wars. Another unit could use this one, and therefore could access this variable. Obviously that would be a mistake, but finalization order is sometimes surprising to programmers, even experienced ones

Comment: `FreeAndNil` is the right choice if the value can be accessed from outside of the class. Just using `Free` will result in a dangling pointer. If there is no access after then you are fine with both ... but if, then you will have a better life with `FreeAndNil`. The `class destructor` is not called at the very end of the application lifetime ... there are more `class destructors`, `finalization` parts, etc.

Comment: AFAICT, another unit can't access the variable in the finalization section. But OK, I'll drop it. And no, Sir Rufo, it is not the right choice in a finalization section. The unit is at its end, nothing can access its variables anymore.

Comment: And the same is true for a class destructor.

Comment: @Rudy Not so. Unit A uses unit B in the implementation. Unit B uses unit A in its implementation. Circular reference in implementation. One unit shuts down first. There's what you say cannot happen.

Comment: A unit shutting down should of course not reference other units in that phase. Then it can't happen.

Comment: @Rudy Well, many units break that rule. Any unit that performs heap allocation in init/finit phase refers to other units. But I do basically agree with you. That part of a unit should be as self contained as possible.

Comment: I see I phrased that wrong. A unit shutting down should not access an *object* owned by another unit. It can access the *code* of the other unit, of course.

Comment: @Rudy It can access both code and data if it wishes. Obviously it should do neither but it is possible.

Comment: Nothing wrong with code or constants or some such (that won't disappear), but it should not access data that might be removed already.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Once you start calling methods, then they might use the data. It's pretty hard to come up with hard and fast rules.